# How to bind a C function for use in a lua script

Tags: c, lua, hook

I have a program written in C code, I would like to implement the use of lua script to allow creating custom code without needing to compile the program again

Is there any way to bind the C code function to be able to use in the lua script?

Example of a C function I have

```
int GetLoginCount(int acc_id) {

    struct acc_info *get = account_info(acc_id);

    if(get == NULL)
        return 0;
    
    return get->login_count;
}
```

How can I use this function in a lua script

I currently have about 800 functions written in C, I need a form where I need to add these functions to be used in lua script and also how I could hook pre and post in my C function using lua script

Comment: I'm not super familiar with lua, but this might be helpful: http://luajit.org/ext_ffi.html
You can then created a shared library using your C object files and call into it with lua. `gcc -aux-info your-source.c` might also be helpful for getting all the functions defined in a specific source file :)

Comment: https://www.lua.org/pil/26.html